# SKView paused automatically resumes

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skview

I am designing a SpriteKit game in swift, and inside my gameplay SKScene I have a method called when I want to pause the game. It looks like this:

```
func pause() {
    view?.paused = true
}
```

The game pauses perfectly, but after a seemingly arbitrary amount of time (1 second to 120 seconds), the game just unpauses/resumes gameplay, without ever calling my resume() method.  I am aware that sprite kit resumes gameplay automatically upon the app becoming active, but I have set a breakpoint in applicationDidBecomeActive, and it is not called. Does anyone know why this is happening?

I know I could set my own paused property and check it every update loop, but I much prefer this elegant solution if I could get it to work!

Comment: so wait.. the game resumes itself while it's still active, or when you come back into the app?

Comment: While it is still active

Comment: how about you delete your resume method altogether and see if it still resumes..  or at least put a breakpoint in there and check where its being called from

Comment: the resume method is never called

Comment: @mogelbuster Where do you call your pause() method ? Also I am just curious does showPauseScreen() is executed ?

Comment: @Whirlwind  I have simplified my code, and have found the same thing still happens.  Please take a look at my edit.  I call the pause() method inside touchesBegan

Comment: What happens if you use scene.view.paused = true instead of view?.paused = true

Comment: @Whirlwind  If i use scene.view.paused = true I get the compile time error message: 'SKScene?' does not have a member named 'view'

Comment: What about this:   self.scene?.view?.paused = true It probably won't change anything, but still you can try...

Comment: @Whirlwind  I think this is because scene is a SKNode property of type SKScene?  and view is a SKScene property of type SKView?.  You either need to use forced-unwrapping scene!.view!.paused = true  or  optional chaining scene?.view?.paused = true. Or use a combination of the two scene?.view!.paused = true.  Or scene!.view?.paused = true.  I've tested all four, none are any different than view?.paused = true

Comment: @Whirlwind the thing is, SKNode has a property scene which is of type SKScene?  but SKScene itself is a descendant of SKNode, thus SKScene confusingly, has an infinite loop reference to itself through its scene property.  Its scene property is equivalent to self.  I could also do scene!.scene!.scene!.scene!.view?.paused = true  (which I actually tried haha) and it is equivalent to view?.paused = true

Comment: @Whirlwind  I tried self.scene?.view?.paused = true,  same thing :-(

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my implementation of ADBannerViewDelegate. Here is the culprit:

```
func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    skView.paused = false
    println("bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError called inside GameViewController class")
}
```

I solved the problem by putting those println calls inside every method that had a .paused = false statement.  Most of the time the banners load fine, but every once in a blue moon they fail and call that method.

Comment: try doing this: if banner != nil { skiver.paused = false println("your println...")} and that should help you out